# Как правильно: трутневый или трутнёвый?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Речь идёт о продукте пчеловодства — трутневом гомогенате.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях — **трутневОй.**

А вот в реальной практике часто встречается ***трутневый***, например: Трутневый гомогенат — это то же самое, что трутневое молочко.

http://narod-lekar.ru/trutnevyi-gomogenat-primenenie/

http://ekolekar.com/trutnevyj-gomogenat-lechebnye-svojstva.html

Вообще говоря, перенос ударения с основы на окончание не кажется оправданным. Может быть, варианты как-то связаны с профессиональной речью.

**Трутневый или трутнёвый**

Из Интернета http://www.pchelovod.info/index.php?showtopic=4913

Я в первые годы занятий пчеловодством также проводил вырезку **трутнёвого** расплода, но сейчас от этого отказался как от бесполезного занятия.

Comment: _часто встречается трутневый_ Так ведь ни по ссылкам, ни по Вашему ответу не понятно, через Е или через Ё оно часто встречается. Вопрос был именно в этом.

Comment: Но в вопросе не было правильного (словарного) варианта - трутневОй, и я как раз обращаю внимание на то, что этот правильный вариант не всегда используется.

Comment: Вопрос был задан в связи с тем, что сын в школе пишет исследовательскую работу про продукты пчеловодства, и хотелось бы, чтобы это было сделано без ошибок. В словаре, действительно, прилагательное от слова "трутень"    - "трутневОй". Но  в профессиональной литературе встречается исключительно "трутнЕвый".

Comment: Наверное, надо использовать профессиональный термин. С другой стороны, Вы уверены, что там Е, а не Ё, ведь раньше Ё очень редко обозначалась. Хорошо бы у настоящих профессионалов спросить.

Answer (score 0):

Ни то ни другое не правильно. Правильно **трутневОй**.